# How to share constants in c#

Tags: c#

I would like to store static variable in single class and use it in different classes.
What is the best practice in C#?

---

**JavaScript example.**
Just for example. I am looking for something like this:

I have single file *MyStaticDataObject.js* with one or more static variables.

```js
const MyStaticDataObject = {
   someKey: someValue,
   anotherKey: anotherValue,
   //...
}
export { MyStaticDataObject };
```

and I can use them in any other file:

```js
import { MyStaticDataObject } from "./MyStaticDataObject.js";

// ... somewhere in code
console.log(`Value of someKey:`, MyStaticDataObject["someKey"]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
namespace nm1 {
internal class MyStaticDataObject {
    public const string Key1 = "Value1";
    public const string Key2 = "Value2";
    }
}
```

In other classes (outside the namespace), reference the namespace `using nm1;` and use it. Otherwise they can be used directly without the `using`

```
using nm1;
internal class TestClass
{
    private string Key1 = MyStaticDataObject.Key1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe late.
But this is a better way - if you need use these constants value frequently.

1. Declare a class with some constants.

```
public class ConstantsClass
{
    public const string ConstName1 = "ConstValue1";
    public const string ConstName2 = "ConstValue2";
    public const string ConstName3 = "ConstValue3";
}
```

2. Using this class in static in code file you want. (C# 6.0 feature)

```
using static ConstantsClass;

namespace YourNamespace
{...
```

3. Use the constanst in the way same as it declared in local.

```
    CallMethod(ConstName1);
```